# Limiting a greedy regular expression

Tags: regex

Example string:

`?token=a12b3c4d5e&time=1417111248&message=Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.&mode=reply&bbcode=1&topic=123456789`

---

Tried capturing the message with `(?:\?|&)message=(.+)&`, however it matches everything until the last `&` character:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.&mode=reply&bbcode=1`

How do I stop the capturing group when it encounters `&` for the first time?

---

Expected result:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.`

Comment: Add a `?` after the `.+` to make it ungreedy.

Comment: `(?:\?|&)message=(.+?)&` or `(?:\?|&)message=([^&]+)&`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a very simple regex as

```
message=[^&]+
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/rJ5qK2/1

- `[^&]+` matches anything other than a `&` one or more time

**OR**

You can also use a non greedy `.+?` as

```
message=(.+?)&
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/rJ5qK2/2